# Hibernate Filter being ignored

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, orm

My application uses Hibernate 5.02 and Wildfly 10 with a PostgreSQL 9.5  database.  I'm trying to enable a filter on a @OneToMany collection held within an entity that is constructed via a NamedQuery.  Unfortunately, it seems as if the filter is just ignored.  Here are the different components, redacted for ease of reading.

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "getAnalystProcess",
        query = "SELECT * FROM analysis.analystprocess WHERE id = :processId",
        resultClass = AnalystProcessEntity.class
)})
@FilterDef(
    name = "analystProcessUnanalyzedMsgsFilter",
    parameters = { @ParamDef(name = "processIds", type = "integer"), @ParamDef(name = "analystIds", type = "integer") })
@Filter(name = "analystProcessUnanalyzedMsgsFilter", condition = "analystprocess_id IN (:processIds) AND id NOT IN (SELECT msg_id FROM analysis.analyzedmsg WHERE analyst_id IN (:analystIds) AND analystprocess_id IN (:processIds)) ORDER BY process_msg_id")
@Entity
@Table(name = "analystprocess", schema = "analyst")
public class AnalystProcessEntity implements JPAEntity {

public static final String GET_PROCESS = "getAnalystProcess";
public static final String MSG_FILTER = "analystProcessUnanalyzedMsgsFilter";
public static final String MSG_FILTER_PROC_ID_PARAM = "processIds";
public static final String MSG_FILTER_ANALYST_ID_PARAM = "analystIds";

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

...

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "process")
@OrderColumn(name = "process_msg_id")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
private List<MsgEntity> msgList;
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "msg", schema = "analyst")
public class MsgEntity implements JPAEntity {

...

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "analystprocess_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private AnalystProcessEntity process;

@Column(name = "process_msg_id")
private Integer processMsgId;
```

---

```
private void buildAnalystProcess() {
    LOG.info("Building AnalystProcessEntity");
    analystUser.getJdbcSession().enableFilter(AnalystProcessEntity.MSG_FILTER)
                .setParameter(AnalystProcessEntity.MSG_FILTER_PROC_ID_PARAM, analystProcessId)
                .setParameter(AnalystProcessEntity.MSG_FILTER_ANALYST_ID_PARAM, analystUser.getId());

    Query query = analystUser.getJdbcSession().getNamedQuery(AnalystProcessEntity.GET_PROCESS)
            .setParameter("processId", analystProcessId);

//        Query query = analystUser.getJdbcSession().createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM analysis.analystprocess WHERE id = :processId")
//                    .setParameter("processId", analystProcessId)
//                    .addEntity(AnalystProcessEntity.class);

    analystProcess = (AnalystProcessEntity) query.getSingleResult();
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE analysis.analystprocess (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        description TEXT,
        created_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
        ...
);

CREATE TABLE analysis.msg (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        analystprocess_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES analysis.analystprocess(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
        process_msg_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        constraint tbl_statusid_analystprocessid unique(status_id, analystprocess_id)
);
```

As seen above, I have also tried the filter on constructing the AnalystProcessEntity class via createNativeQuery instead of getNamedQuery and no luck.

I also added a defaultCondition with hardcoded values into the @FilterDef just to see if it would execute the default condition and it still didn't.

I've tried the @Filter above the entity definition as well as above the class definition.  I even came across a blog post which made it sound like the condition references entity fields (variable names) and not table fields (column names).  Trying to stick to Java naming conventions in the Entity and Postgres naming conventions in the table, so I tried switching the references in the condition and to no avail.

I have sql logging turned on in Hibernate and the condition doesn't show up anywhere, as if it's just simply being ignored.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was that I had the @FilterDef applied to the wrong class.  It was my presumption that because I was constructing the AnalystProcessEntity which holds the MsgEntity collection (which I am trying to filter), that the @FilterDef would be applied to the AnalystProcessEntity class.  Instead, it needs to be applied to the entity that it's actually filtering (hindsight being 20/20, that's pretty obvious).

Also, the actual condition needed to be modified to use complete references within the sub-select query.

I hope this helps someone at some point...

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "getAnalystProcess",
        query = "SELECT * FROM analysis.analystprocess WHERE id = :processId",
        resultClass = AnalystProcessEntity.class
)})
@Filter(name = "analystProcessUnanalyzedMsgsFilter", condition = "id NOT IN (SELECT amsg.msg_id FROM analysis.analyzedmsg amsg WHERE amsg.analyst_id IN (:analystIds) AND amsg.analystprocess_id IN (:processIds))")
@Entity
@Table(name = "analystprocess", schema = "analyst")
public class AnalystProcessEntity implements JPAEntity {

public static final String GET_PROCESS = "getAnalystProcess";
public static final String MSG_FILTER = "analystProcessUnanalyzedMsgsFilter";
public static final String MSG_FILTER_PROC_ID_PARAM = "processIds";
public static final String MSG_FILTER_ANALYST_ID_PARAM = "analystIds";

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

...

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "process")
@OrderColumn(name = "process_msg_id")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
private List<MsgEntity> msgList;
```

---

```
@FilterDef(
    name = "analystProcessUnanalyzedMsgsFilter",
    parameters = { @ParamDef(name = "processIds", type = "integer"), @ParamDef(name = "analystIds", type = "integer") })
@Entity
@Table(name = "msg", schema = "analyst")
public class MsgEntity implements JPAEntity {

...

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "analystprocess_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private AnalystProcessEntity process;

@Column(name = "process_msg_id")
private Integer processMsgId;
```

Additionally, I ran into another problem with null's appearing in the collection, despite the fact that I am using an @OrderColumn, which I thought fixed that issue.  It seems that with the use of the @Filter, null's are inserted in place of what ended up being filtered OUT (excluded).